# What Is The Relationship between "Users & Groups" and /etc/group?

Tags: macos, permission, group

I want to setup a `wireshark` group so I can run it without being `root`.  I tried using the `System Preferences` tool, `Users & Groups`, to add a `wireshark` group but I didn't see anything show up in `/etc/group`.

Where is the group stored if it's not `/etc/group`.  Do groups set up in `User & Groups` have any relationship with the `chmod`/`chgrp` permissions?

I installed Wireshark via MacPorts and it doesn't currently set the permissions correctly to run as a normal user.

Comment: I'll answer the groups architecture question, Setting up Wireshark to run as an administrator is all you should need. Why not ask a follow on question explaining how far you've got - and what specific error message or installation guide you followed to obtain and install wire shark. Most people will point you to http://brew.sh and to run  ` brew cask install wireshark-chmodbpf` which sets permissions on the bpf device for you.

Answer (score 2):

That `/etc/group` file only exists to let the system function in single user boot mode. I wouldn't rely on it for anything other than a possible sanity check for known system groups.

You'll want to use `dscl` the directory service command line (and associated dsXXX commands to interact with whatever directory services external to the local store) to retrieve group and user information from the database that normal run time changes and lookups happen.

The manual page can get you started and then Apple developer documentation and specific sites (like this one and code posted at GitHub ) might be good places for follow on research and questions on syntax / scripting / usage.

Also - I would install [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and see the output from `brew info wireshark` which details the tool to script setting up a security group and change permissions on the device(s) Wireshark needs to own for capture.

If you're not into that package manager - here's a script that might do the trick.

- https://gist.github.com/breiter/cbf0307c671f8bc0a7c4

Comment: I already have MacPorts installed so I don't want to install a second package manager. I actually installed Wireshark through MacPorts but it doesn't set the permissions correctly. I'll look at `dscl` when I get back to my machine.

Comment: @StephenRasku Fair enough - looks like ports has known about this for 7 years or so - https://trac.macports.org/ticket/26293 - what I can see is they just assign it to root - see my edit above.

Comment: That `.plist` file worked.  Thanks.

However, I looked at `dscl` but I couldn't figure out how to do anything. I keep getting "Cannot open remote host, error: DSOpenDirServiceErr".

Comment: @Stephen Rasku Try-`dscl /Local/Default -list /Groups PrimaryGroupID`.